# How can I read out an <input> value via the name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I've got the following output in my HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="28" name="variation_id">
```

This value is generated dynamically. I want to write an If else statement that is dependant on this value i.e. the "28". I'm not quite sure on how to target this value since it has no ID. Is there a code to read out this value, via the "name" attribute?

I want to write the if else statement in Javascript.

Comment: Just as a side not, the number in the ***value*** attribute is actually a string. Depending on how you use this, you may need to run `parseInt([value]);` (replacing [value] with the value) in order to get a number you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like this one

```
 var val = document.getElementsByName('variation_id')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you only have the one element with that `name`:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByName('variation_id')[0];

if (elem.value == '28') {
    // it has that value, do something
}
else {
    // it doesn't have that value, do something else.
}
```

Or, in more up to date browsers:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('input[name="variation_id"]');

if (elem.value == '28') {
    // it has that value, do something
}
else {
    // it doesn't have that value, do something else.
}
```

References:

- [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelector).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
var value = document.getElementsByName("variation_id")[0].value;
```